# How to Determine if a String starts with exact number of zeros?

Tags: java

How can I know if my string exactly starts with {n} number of leading zeros?
For example below, the conditions would return true but my real intention is to check if the string actually starts with only 2 zeros.

```
String str = "00063350449370"

if (str.startsWith("00")) { // true
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
if ( str.startsWith("00") && ! str.startsWith("000") ) {
   // ..
}
```

This will make sure that the string starts with "00", but not a longer string of zeros.

Comment: Perfect, and avoids regular expressions.

Comment: @Bathsheba why insinuate that regular expression should be avoided?

Comment: Of all the answers, this one is by far the clearest, and possibly the fastest in execution. **That** is what you get when you avoid regular expressions.

Comment: what if the string is String str = "00003350449370"?

Comment: @yonan2236 Then it begins with `000`. It's the same thing that happened to you with the "00", but used to your advantage.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this regex

```
boolean res = s.matches("00[^0]*");
```

Comment: Wouldn't this reject Strings that have a 0 anywhere else after the first three characters?

Comment: No, matches starts matching from the beginning of the string

Answer (score 1):

How about?

```
final String zeroes = "00";
final String zeroesLength = zeroes.length();
str.startsWith(zeroes) && (str.length() == zeroes.length() || str.charAt(zeroes.length()) != '0')
```

Comment: @FastSnail To avoid indexOutOfBoundExceptions with charAt I assume.

Comment: Use `char 0` and not `int 0`. Like `charAt() != '0'`

Comment: Sorry, just made it more generic. If you check directly if the char after the zeroes is not a zero you might get an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`. So if the string starts with the amount of zeroes you want, and is exactly those zeroes, then you return true.

Answer (score 1):

Slow but:

```
if (str.matches("(?s)0{3}([^0].*)?") {
```

This uses `(?s)` DOTALL option to let `.` also match line-breaks.

`0{3}` is for 3 matches.

Answer (score 1):

How about using a regular expression?

```
0{n}[^0]*
```

where n is the number of leading '0's you want. You can utilise the Java regex API to check if the input matches the expression:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("0{2}[^0]*"); // n = 2 here
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
if (matcher.matches()) {
    // code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression to evaluate the `String` value:

```
String str = "00063350449370";
String pattern = "[0]{2}[1-9]{1}[0-9]*"; // [0]{2}[1-9]{1} starts with 2 zeros, followed by a non-zero value, and maybe some other numbers: [0-9]*
if (Pattern.matches(pattern, str))
{
    // DO SOMETHING
}
```

There might be a better regular expression to resolve this, but this should give you a general idea how to proceed if you choose the regular expression path.

Answer (score 0):

The long way

```
    String TestString = "0000123";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\A0+(?=\\d)");
    Matcher matcher = p.matcher(TestString);

    while (matcher.find()) {
          System.out.print("Start index: " + matcher.start());
          System.out.print(" End index: " + matcher.end() + " ");
          System.out.println(" Group: " + matcher.group());
    }
```

Your probably better off with a small for loop though

```
    int leadZeroes;
    for (leadZeroes=0; leadZeroes<TestString.length(); leadZeroes++)
        if (TestString.charAt(leadZeroes) != '0')
            break;

    System.out.println("Count of Leading Zeroes: " + leadZeroes);
```